# Remove the element in list

Tags: prolog

I want to remove the element in list1 when it is equal to element in list2.
The query and the expected output is:

```
filter( [[1,2,3],[1]] , [[1]] , X ).
X = [[1, 2, 3]] ;

filter( [[1,2,3],[1],[2,3,4],[2]] , [[1],[2]] , X ).
X = [[1, 2, 3],[2,3,4]] ;
```

What I have done right now is :

```
filter(_,[],_). 
filter([A|B],[A|D],E):-
    filter(B,D,E).
filter([A|B],[C|D],[A|E]):-
    A\=C,
    filter(B,D,E).
```

but it seems not right and gives the output like this:

```
11 ?- filter([[1,2,3],[1]],[[1]],X).
X = [[1, 2, 3]|_G488] ;
```

Can anyone help? Maybe I was near success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program will not work correctly because you are removing one element from the second list each time. Also your base case (the first clause) should not be an uninstantiated variable (that is what is giving you the `|_G488` in your output.

You have to iterate over the first list filtering the elements found in the second list, but not remove the elements of the second list.

For example:

```
filter([], _, []).
filter([Item|L1], L2, L3):-
  (member(Item, L2) -> L4=L3;L3=[Item|L4]),
  filter(L1, L2, L4).
```

The first clase is the base case of the recursion. It states that the output for an empty list would be an empty list.
The second clause checks to see if the first item of the input list is found on the second list. If it is found then it won't be added to the resulting list; otherwise it is added. Then it recursively calls itself with the rest of the input list. 
But in no case it removes the elements from the second list.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the lazy way would be to use the build-ins, `findall/3` and `member/2`:

```
filter( Xs , Ys , Rs ) :-
  findall( X , ( member(X,Xs), \+ member(X,Ys) ) , Rs ) .
```

which says to find all `X` such that `X` is a member of the list `Xs` and `Xs is *not* a member of the list`Ys`.

Assuming your instructor wants you to come up with your own implementation, you probably first want to *decompose* your problem. You need to do two things:

- Iterate over a list, removing items that are found in another list.
- Given an item, determine whether it is contained in another list.

Both of these are simple. To determine if an item is contained in a list, you could say something like:

```
contained_in( X , [X|Ys] ) :- % if we find the item in the list,
  ! .                         % - we succeed and eliminate any alternatives.
contained_in( X , [_|Ys] ) :- % otherwise, we discard the head of the list,
  contained_in(X,Ys) .        % - and keep looking by recursing down.
```

The actual filtering is pretty simple, too:

```
filter( []     , _  , []    ) .   % once the source list is exhausted, we're done.
filter( [X|Xs] , Ys , [X|R] ) :-  % otherwise...
  \+ contained_in(X,Ys) ,         % - if the current list item is not contained in the list of items to be removed,
  ! ,                             % - cut off alternatives,
  filter( Xs , Ys , R ) .         % - add the current item to the result list and recurse down.
  .                               % 
filter( [_|Xs] , Ys , R ) :-      % if the current list item IS contained in the list of items to be removed,
  filter(Xs , Ys , R )            % - discard it and recurse down.
  .                               % Easy!
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `filter` is just `subtract` available with many Prolog systems (I've tested with B-Prolog, SWI-Prolog and ECLiPSe):

```
?- subtract( [[1,2,3],[1]] , [[1]] , X ).
X = [[1, 2, 3]].

?- subtract( [[1,2,3],[1],[2,3,4],[2]] , [[1],[2]] , X ).
X = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]].
```

You can look at the sources of SWI-Prolog or ECLiPSe for implementation details.